# A lot of public—why isn't it correct?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

Why is the following not correct?

> There was **a lot of public** at the concert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Public***, under most circumstances, is an adjective. The grammar you have used would indicate that it was a mass noun, which it is not.

***The public*** can be thought of as a set phrase that means "people in general, not part of some group determined by context". So, if the people running a museum talk about "the public", it means people who don't work for the museum - and will generally be used about **members of** the public who come to the museum. It's also usually used for generalisations, and people will usually accept that there are exceptions without needing to say so.

> "**The public** won't know why they shouldn't touch the exhibits. Thousand-year-old artefacts being fragile just isn't something that goes through their minds."

*The public* also behaves as a grammatical plural most of the time, despite looking like a singular:

> **The public** are easily manipulated.

(It's possible that this could be ellipsis of "members of the public")

Because it acts like a plural made up of distinct, countable individuals, I would usually use ***many*** to indicate large quantity:

> There were **many** of **the public** at the concert.

That doesn't come across as wrong, to me, just unnatural. In that case, and I can't really explain why, I would use:

> There were many **members of the public** at the concert.

Though I'm not sure why you can just say ***many people***, and then specify *in the audience* to make sure people know what you're talking about. Also, despite some people's insistence on rules about countability, it would be common to say "lots of people", so you could have>

> There were **lots of people in the audience** at the concernt.

Some hidebound teachers might insist on it being "many" rather than "lots of", but it would be a rare native speaker who would bat an eyelid.

Important point, though - if ***public*** is being a noun rather than an adjective, it needs a definite article - ***the public***.